# UserDefaults in system preference pane installed for multiple users in OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, preferences, nsuserdefaults

I have a background-only app that is controlled via a preference pane in the system preferences. To communicate between pref pane and app I use distributed notifications. User defaults are shared via [`[NSUserDefaults addSuiteNamed:]`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/addSuiteNamed:). This all works out very well.

The problem occurs when the user installs the pref pane "for all users", when prompted by the system preference pane. In this case prefs get written to `~/Library/Preferences/`, same as when installed "for this user only". (I think this is the correct behavior.) 
However, when the prefpane reads a default key, the prefpane seems to be looking at `/Library/Preferences/`, not in the user's home directory.

To sum it up:

- prefs pane installed in: ~/Library/PreferencePanes/

  - Defaults written to: ~/Library/Preferences/
  - Defaults read from: ~/Library/Preferences/
- prefs pane installed in: /Library/PreferencePanes/

  - Defaults written to: ~/Library/Preferences/
  - Defaults read from: /Library/Preferences/

Could anyone shed some light as to where things go wrong?

Thanks,
Kolja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have essentially the same design as Growl. We use CFPreferences to read and write the user's preferences. See [GrowlPreferencesController](http://growl.info/hg/growl/file/c85bf1983721/Core/Source/GrowlPreferencesController.m#l64) and [the macros in GrowlDefinesInternal.h](http://growl.info/hg/growl/file/c85bf1983721/Common/Source/GrowlDefinesInternal.h#l257). The distributed notification cues both the background app and the prefpane to re-read the preferences.

(Don't take it quite as far as we do, though—it's fine to use NSNumber, NSDictionary, etc. with Core Foundation, and it's much easier to read.)

Comment: Is that header file standard C, or am I looking at Objective-C? I'm mostly curious because of all the function macros - why do people writing C (or Objective-C?) tend to do so much with function macros rather than just writing a function? I'm pretty well-versed in C but my first programming language was Java; as a consequence I find C function macros pretty sketchy. Maybe you can only speak for yourself on this one, but I am curious to hear about this from a serious developer.

Comment: It's both. It adapts to whatever `#include`d or `#import`ed it. As for the macros, I don't know why the person who wrote them made them macros; they may very well be better as functions.

Comment: I was already working on source code based on growl, which I wrote two years ago. i have updated my sources to the way growl handles the stuff. The problem is prefs are still not working when the prefpane is installed for all users. Can you confirm that the growl source can handle this situation, because growl comes with an installer that doesn't leave you the choice to install the prefpane for all users.

Comment: “growl comes with an installer that doesn't leave you the choice to install the prefpane for all users.” Yes it does. What it doesn't do is offer you the choice to install it only for yourself; that option is disabled (and I don't know why).

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing that out. I will reevaluate my code, because if the growl code does what I want, the error must be in my implementation. Thanks again.

Comment: Update: We've since removed the install-for-only-yourself option. It caused too much confusion, especially in upgrading, as people didn't make the same choice for the upgrade as they did for the original installation and ended up with two installations.